# MATLAB, about textread function

Tags: matlab

I have problem with my code that uses `textread` function to *.txt file scan.

From `uigetfile` command, code read *.txt files in specific folder.
But in there, some files have a different form from others.
So 'textread' function doesn't work.

Is there any method to ignore those files(have a different form.) and only read correct files?

This is my code:

```
[handles.FileName_h,handles.PathName] = uigetfile({'*.txt'}, 'TXT File(*.txt)','MultiSelect','ON');
FN=handles.FileName{1,syn};
[Date,Time,T10,T20,T30,P10]=textread(sprintf('%s',FN),'%q%q%n%n%n%n%*[^\n]','headerlines',2);
```

Comment: What would "a different form" entail?

Comment: You could use `try/catch` to ignore errors